# Serilog .NET with Azure Table Storage

Tags: .net-core, logging, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

I hear great things about Serilog and I would like to utilize it in my .NET Core API.

Due to the low cost of Azure Table Storage, it is my preferred "database". I see Serilog has a sink for that.

My question is the following:

In my current iteration I have a custom class (LogDetail) which contains the calling method, the authenticated user (from the HttpContext) if any, the stack trace, the calling application etc.

How can I incorporate my custom object to be logged alongside the columns that Serilog will create in Azure Table Storage? Preferably not as a JSON string but instead, each property of the object should be in its own column.

Is this doable or do I need to write a custom sink?

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to add custom property in azure table storage when using Serilog 2.x.  I found no direct way to add properties in LogEventEntity.

**Soultion:** [If you want implement it, you should use SDK to do it.](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables.md#add-an-entity-to-a-table)

---

What I have tried.

#### Just the test result, not the solution, solution is the link above

**AzureTableStorageTableResolver.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;

namespace AspCore7_Web_Identity
{
    public class AzureTableStorageTableResolver : ILogEventEnricher
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public AzureTableStorageTableResolver(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
        {
            var tableName = logEvent.Properties["TableName"]?.ToString() ?? "default";

            var myArray = _configuration.GetSection("Table1").Get<string[]>(); 

            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
            {
                var myProperty = new LogEventProperty(myArray[i], new ScalarValue("DefaultValue"));
                logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(myProperty);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILogger>(sp =>
        {
            return new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
            .Enrich.With(new AzureTableStorageTableResolver(builder.Configuration))
            .CreateLogger();
        });
```

And I found the properties added to Data column.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the detailed code. Is there a way I can split what's in the Data column in their own columns? For example, in your case, you'll have one column for every property in the json array.

Comment: @achilles My sample code just tell you that there is no direct way to add new properties directly to the entity.

Comment: @achilles But if we use the SDK, it can be achieved, you can refer to the link in my answer.